Why I cannot set the correct username for my ssh on VScode
I have been using VScode for remote coding for years now but suddenly instead of root@ip I have some weird username like 1000hroot@ip as in the picture :

This is my ssh conf file :
Host 65.109.xxx.xxx
  HostName 65.109.xxx.xxx
  User root

The auth is not accepted from the server since the username is wrong, what should I do?

Verify the credentials in the client area of your host or open a support ticket?

@DarkBee I am the server owner, should I open a suppor ticket to myself?
